# DNA Sequencing - Sanger termination method: What effects will more ddNTPs in solution have on the resolution on agarose gel via electrophoresis?

Tags: genetics, dna-sequencing, gel-electrophoresis

Say instead of a small amount of ddNTPs, you add a significant percent of ddNTPs to dNTPs. I was thinking this would reduce the resolution for larger fragments due to more ddNTPs terminating elongation earlier on.

I am doing a project on Sanger Sequencing and was wondering this, thank you. (Any suggestions would be appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The greater the ratio of ddNTPs to dNTPs, the more frequently ddNTPs will terminate the reaction, resulting in shorter mean fragment size. However, Sanger sequencing is not done with agarose gels. The result visualizing a Sanger reaction on agarose, using more ddNTPs would result in a smear closer to the bottom. For actually visualizing the sequences on acrylamide, or with capillaries, increasing the ddNTPs would reduce the resolution of longer fragments. It is a balance you need to optimize.